# Test using the CssSelector

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shdocvw

There is a button and in the html file it describes as following.

```
<input class="add-to-basket" type="submit" value="Add to basket"/>
```

I have created the following cording for the above html file.

```
var addToBasketLink = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#Add to basket"));
            addToBasketLink.Click();
```

I need to do is, when I click the Add to basket button, it should display the View Basket button above of the page.

Thankx in advance

Comment: Is that javascript? Where are `.FindElement()`, `By` and `.Click()` defined?

Comment: Code formatting is good, if you want anyone to read and answer your question.

Comment: @jrummell That's C#, using Interop.SHDocVw to query the DOM from the test/spec, probably using WatiN or something similar.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't Selenium?

Comment: Sorry I didnt see this before and It is Selenium. Yes worked with ASP.Net MVC3.

Answer (score 1):

The # selector is used for ID, and your input does not have an ID attribute. You want the class selector, which is a period, followed by the class name:

```
By.CssSelector(".add-to-basket")
```

Comment: When I tried (By.CssSelector("input[value='Add to basket']"));, it worked fine and @mgnoonan I tried your code with the class name, but it doesnot work. Can you / anyone please let me know about the difference between these two syntaxes.

Comment: If this is Selenium, I can't answer your question. In jQuery the CSS selectors follow the rule as I specified, so there may be some difference between jQuery and Selenium.

Comment: Could also try `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[class='.add-to-basket']"));`, should work

Comment: Thank you MilkyWayJoe and mgnoonan for your comments and I used the code I have mentioned above